# How to find out the size of an array allocated on the heap in C?

Tags: arrays, c, size

I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE(a) (sizeof(a))/(sizeof(a[0]))
#define ARRAYSIZEWITHPTR(a) (&(a)[1] - a)

int main (void){

  int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int* pArray = array;
  int* p = calloc(ARRAYSIZE(array), sizeof(int));
  
  assert(NULL != p);
  
  printf("size of array: %ld\n", ARRAYSIZE(array));
  printf("size of pArray: %ld\n", ARRAYSIZE(pArray));
  printf("size of p: %ld\n", ARRAYSIZE(p));
  printf("size of pArray: %ld\n", ARRAYSIZEWITHPTR(pArray));
  printf("size of p: %ld\n", ARRAYSIZEWITHPTR(p));

  free(p);

return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program, I get the following warning messages from gcc:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:33: warning: division ‘sizeof (int *) / sizeof (int)’ does not compute the number of array elements [-Wsizeof-pointer-div]
    5 | #define ARRAYSIZE(a) (sizeof(a))/(sizeof(a[0]))
      |                                 ^
test.c:15:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘ARRAYSIZE’
   15 |   printf("size of pArray: %ld\n", ARRAYSIZE(pArray));
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~
test.c:11:8: note: first ‘sizeof’ operand was declared here
   11 |   int* pArray = array;
      |        ^~~~~~
test.c:5:33: warning: division ‘sizeof (int *) / sizeof (int)’ does not compute the number of array elements [-Wsizeof-pointer-div]
    5 | #define ARRAYSIZE(a) (sizeof(a))/(sizeof(a[0]))
      |                                 ^
test.c:16:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘ARRAYSIZE’
   16 |   printf("size of p: %ld\n", ARRAYSIZE(p));
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~
test.c:12:8: note: first ‘sizeof’ operand was declared here
   12 |   int* p = calloc(ARRAYSIZE(array), sizeof(int));
      |        ^
```

And the following is the program output:

```
size of array: 5
size of pArray: 2
size of p: 2
size of pArray: 1
size of p: 1
```

As is evident from the program output, I get the correct value only when the macro is invoked with the array name as the argument. However, isn't array name the pointer to the first element of the array? If so, what is the quintessential difference between invoking the macro with the array name (which yields the correct result) a opposed to the pointer pointing to an array on the heap (which doesn't yield the correct result?)

As can be seen from the source code, I have tried both the macro approaches to get the size of the array created on the heap, without success.

So the next question is, is it possible at all to get the size of the array created thus on the heap using `calloc(`) in C programming?

TIA

Comment: You can't know from the pointers: but you just allocated the arrays, so you know. Otherwise you need the size as a separate piece of data,  for example a function definition `void func(int *array, size_t len)` or by using a sentinel value when you traverse an array (such as a C string has).

Comment: Aside: please use `%zu` format spec for a `size_t` argument, not `%ld` which is incorrect.

Comment: OT: `#define ARRAYSIZE(a) ...` wants to be wrapped in another level of parentheses (to ensure division has expected precedence.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standardized way to find out how much allocated memory a pointer returned from `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` points to.  The programmer is expected to keep track of that himself.

In your example, since `p` and `pArray` have type `int *` `sizeof(p)` and `sizeof(pArray)` are giving you the size of the type `int *` which is most likely 8 on your system.

> However, isn't array name the pointer to the first element of the array?

No, an array name is an array, however in most contexts the array *decays* to a pointer to its first element.  One of the cases where this does *not* happen is when the array is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, So since `array` has array type, `sizeof(array)` gives you the size of the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

There are some standardized ways to know the allocation size of a chunk of memory returned by `malloc()` and friends (`calloc`, `realloc`), they are just not standardized by the C standard itself.

- On GNU/Linux, the function [`malloc_usable_size()`](https://manned.org/malloc_usable_size.3) does what you need. It is part of the GNU C standard, which is a widely available extension of the C standard.
- On macOS, the functions [`malloc_size()` and `malloc_good_size()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/malloc_size.3.html) serve the same purpose.
- On Windows using MSVC, there's [`_msize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/z2s077bc(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) instead.
- Depending on your system, there may also be other ways.

As per the GNU standard, `malloc_usable_size()` is definitely available in most major Linux distributions that ship with [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). You will have to compile with `-std=gnu99` instead of `-std=c99` (in general `-std=gnuXX` instead of `-std=cXX`).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE(a) (sizeof(a))/(sizeof(a[0]))
#define ARRAYSIZEWITHPTR(a) (&(a)[1] - a)

int main (void){
    int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int* p = calloc(ARRAYSIZE(array), sizeof(int));
    assert(p != NULL);

    printf("Allocated size: %zu\n", malloc_usable_size(p));
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Allocated size: 24
```